# Why no socket function name to select in the completion menu?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, ctags

I create ctags for C with the following command:

```
mkdir .vim/tags
ctags -R -I __THROW -I __attribute_pure__ -I __nonnull -I __attribute__ --file-scope=yes --langmap=c:+.h --languages=c,c++ --links=yes --c-kinds=+p --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q \
-f .vim/tags/systag /usr/include/* --exclude="/usr/include/python2.7" --exclude="/usr/include/python3.4" --exclude="/usr/include/python3.4m"
```

I have this configuration in my `.vimrc`:

```
vim .vimrc
set tags+=$HOME/.vim/tags/systag
```

Now, when I edit a C file, when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>
after `soc`, a completion menu pops up with many functions of the socket function family, but why no `socket` function listed here?

[image]

Comment: 1. Use `<C-x><C-]>` to complete from tags. 2. Read `:help tags`, `:help ctags`, and `:help ins-completion`.